# Apache and GitLab on same server

Tags: git, apache, nginx, port, gitlab

I have a problem, that nginx is saying that :80 port is already in use by gitlab.

By editing `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` I've changed

```
external_url 'http://git.host.com:81'
```

And it's not working.

Tried to change `/opt/gitlab/embedded/conf/nginx.conf` port to 81 - same problem.

After each action I executed

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure && gitlab-ctl restart
```

What I`m doing wrong? How to change gitlab port to another one?

Comment: make sure you edit and reconfigure as sudo

Comment: @Corbin If OP wasn't doing it with `sudo` probably system would inform him about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few hours of brainstorming I did found a solution to my problem:

I just needed to open 81 port. :)

Answer (score 1):

First,

```
sudo -e /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

Then, change `external_url` from `example.com` to `example.com:81`.

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```